# Script in Powershell to download xml append to file

Tags: xml, powershell

My goal is to create a schedule task download a XML file from Internet and append to a file. Sometimes the XML file has information and sometimes doesn't, only the header.
When has information the file content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Export>
.
.
.
</Export>
```

When it doesn't:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Export/>
```

The content of the final file will be something like:

```
<Export>
.
.
.
"content appended" 
.
.
</Export>
```

This is the script to download XML

```
$url = "http://www.website/objxml"
$input = "path to xml file"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $input)
```

I don't know if the term remove/create text will be the best solution.
Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: HI, you can use `Get-Content` and `Out-File`, it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41231856/edit) to edit your question and add your code, then delete your comment.

Comment: Hello @sodawillow tried with `$SourceFile = "path\obj2.xml"`

`$Match = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'`

`(Get-Content $SourceFile) | % {if ($_ -match $Match){$_}} | Set-Content $SourceFile`

but I don't have the need to put text in the file when doesn't have "information", something like, If content = "..." don't execute 
and I also have a problem because I have something like 
`<export>`... `</export>`...  every time I execute the script and the program that reads the XML gives an error.

Comment: [Edit. Your. Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41231856/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so rather than using `.DownloadFile` Use `.DownloadString` It will output the url contents in to the variable we specify:

```
[xml]$XML = $webclient.DownloadString("Http://Url-To-XML.com")

if($XML.xml.Export.childnodes.count -ne $null)
{
     $XML | Out-File C:\Temp\Data.xml -Append
}
else
{
   #No data in XML
}
```

You will need to tweak the `if` statement because i cant see the whole xml document. Now that the XML is stored in `$XML` you can dot walk through it to get to a point in the XML tree where you can check its members, Here I check the value of `.Count` on the `childnodes` method but you can check the value of a variable in the document if its easier.

`$XML` will be the document so you can manipulate it, strip sections, add and modify parts all in side the script.

Comment: Hello @Nick, the XML has always content if the is no orders.
When has orders the file looks like `<Export>
<Objednavka>
 <Fakturacni_adresa>
  <NazevFirmy /> 
  <Ulice></Ulice> 
  <Cislo /> 
  <Mesto></Mesto> 
  <PSC></PSC> 
  <Stat></Stat> 
  </Fakturacni_adresa>
 <DodaciAdresa>
  <NazevFirmy></NazevFirmy> 
  <Ulice></Ulice> 
  <Cislo /> 
  <Mesto></Mesto> 
  <PSC></PSC> 
  <Stat></Stat> 
  </DodaciAdresa>
</Objednavka>
.
</Export>`

Comment: if "doesn't have" information the content file is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Export/>`
the information to append must be inside the "<export></export> 
Can you help me to construct the script? many many thanks

Comment: Did you try run the code example above? It should solve your problem.